# Expectation of inner product between random vector and constant vector $\mathbb{E}_{{\bf{\epsilon}}}[\langle {\bf{x}}, {\bf{\epsilon}}\rangle] = ?$

Tags: regression, probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value

Suppose I have a random vector ${\bf{\epsilon}}$ such that 
$$\mathbb{E}_{{\bf{\epsilon}}}[{\bf{\epsilon}}] = 0$$
I want to find the expectation of the inner product between another vector which is constant/deterministic and the random vector, i.e.
$$\mathbb{E}_{{\bf{\epsilon}}}[\langle {\bf{x}}, {\bf{\epsilon}}\rangle] = ?$$

I have no clue how to go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dot product is a sum of products of corresponding elements. Since each element $\epsilon_i$ has an expectation of 0, it is also $E[\epsilon_i  x_i] = 0$. The expectation of the sum, i.e. dot product, is therefore also 0.
(btw. the variance would depend on the values of x).

Answer (score 1):

Because the style of the question has the flavour of an exercise of a stats class, just a few hints:

1. Think about, what an expectation of a vector means for its components. What does []=0 say about the expectation of the components of $\epsilon$)
2. Try to write the inner product as a sum, it demystifies things.
3. Think about the linearity of the expectation. If you don't know what I mean, look it up at wikipedia.

Then the exercise is almost solved.